# Python - Cosine Similarity with Nested Dictionary Structure

Tags: python, dictionary, svm, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to perform a cosine similarity of the vector of food amounts between various students. I have a CSV file that contains:

```
Student   food      amount
John      apple       15
John      banana      20
John      orange      1
John      grape       3
Ben       apple       2
Ben       orange      4
Ben       strawberry  8
Andrew    apple       10
Andrew    watermelon  3
```

The following code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(dict)
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        data[row['Student']][row['food']] = row['amount']
```

gives me a structure like this:

```
{'John': {'apple': 15, 'banana': 20, 'orange': 1, 'grape': 3}, 
 'Ben': {'apple': 2, 'orange': 4, 'strawberry': 8}, #etc.
}
```

I want to turn these dictionaries into vectors where the length of the vector is the number of unique food items and a food item that is not eaten by a student will default to 0 so that:

```
for John: [15,20,1,3,0] corresponds to [apple,banana,orange,grape,strawberry,watermelon]
for Ben: [2,0,4,0,8,0] corresponds to [apple,banana,orange,grape,strawberry,watermelon] #etc
```

I would then output a cosine similarity matrix between each student. 
thanks for taking the time to read. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Common ;) can't possibly already have tried a lot since last question you asked about the previous step (where you also didn't accept the answer you considered correct)

Comment: Where is your code so far? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> D = {'John': {'apple': 15, 'banana': 20, 'orange': 1, 'grape': 3}, 
...  'Ben': {'apple': 2, 'orange': 4, 'strawberry': 8}, #etc.
... }
```

Start by making a list of all the unique keys

```
>>> all_keys = sorted({k for i in D for k in D[i]})
>>> all_keys
['apple', 'banana', 'grape', 'orange', 'strawberry']
```

Now you can loop over those keys for each person

```
>>> {k:[D[k].get(i, 0) for i in all_keys] for k in D}
{'John': [15, 20, 3, 1, 0], 'Ben': [2, 0, 0, 4, 8]}
```